Is $\{0,\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ totally disconnected but not discrete?
The commonly mentioned examples of totally disconnected  but non-discrete spaces in books  are Cantor set, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$,  and $p$-adic integers. I am looking the following one if it works:
I am trying to see if $X:=\{0,\frac{1}{n}: n\ge 1\}$ with subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$ is totally disconnected but not discrete.
To prove totally disconnectedness, we take a subset $S$ of at least two points and show that it is not connected.
Choose smallest $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}\in S$.
Then we can separate $1/k$ and remaining part of $S$ by two disjoint open sets in $S$: namely, take $0<\varepsilon < |\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}|$. Then

$(\frac{1}{k}-\varepsilon, \frac{1}{k}+\varepsilon)\cap S =\{\frac{1}{k}\}$.

$(-\varepsilon, \frac{1}{k-1}+\varepsilon)\cap S$ does not contain $\frac{1}{k}$.

The union of two open subsets of $S$ above is $S$; hence $S$ is disconnected.


For non-discreteness of $X$, there is a point in $X$ which is limit of a sequence not containing that point, hence $X$ is not discrete.

Question Is the assertion about $X$ and above proof correct?


That seems correct to me.
